# Go To Frame After Drag and Drop AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

```
on(press)
{
    _root.coffee.startDrag(true);

}

on(release)
{
    this._x=738.95;
    this._y=400.20;

    _root.coffee.stopDrag();

    **gotoAndStop(20);** <- THIS
}
```

I'm trying to go the frame 20 once coffee is already dragged and dropped to its location.
I can't manage to do this, help please!

Comment: How can you determine that it is already in place? Why you using `_root`? Is script written on Button or on MovieClip?

Comment: Did you try "_root.gotoAndStop(20);"?

Comment: @dhc I put the _root. in and it worked. Thanks! :)

Comment: @aayat ...and do you know ***why*** to include `_root`?

Comment: @ManofSnow Errr...not very sure

Comment: @aayat  Learn programming, I will tell you this: you want the root to go to the frame, not the MovieClip.

Comment: Actionscript is assuming that you mean you want the movieclip that contained the code to go to frame 20. `_root` is a way to get back to the main timeline.  Leaving it out is essentially the same as writing `_this.gotoAndStop(20);`  `_root` can be dangerous to use, because you don't always know for certain when you start nesting code and symbols that the timeline `_root` is referring to will actually be what you expect it to be. But, if you're just getting started with programming and/or Actionscript, it's probably fine to use right now as long as you know the risks for future projects.